# What APIs in iOS 11 support FLAC?

Tags: ios, ios11, avasset, flac

I'm trying to play back FLAC files in an app, but when I create an `AVURLAsset`, the `isPlayable` property is `false` for FLAC files.

A [number](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/6fh4xf/feature_flac_support_in_ios/) [of](https://www.imore.com/how-play-flac-files-iphone-and-ipad) [sources](https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/06/flac-ios-11/) have reported that the Files app in iOS 11 is able to Preview FLAC files, so I'm wondering if there's any official API support for FLAC for developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 11.2, the `AVURLAsset` property `isPlayable` returns `true` for FLAC files.